Conditionally set Sagemaker Pipeline Parameters
I'm trying to add the ability to enable/disable spot training to an existing Sagemaker pipeline. In order to do so, I need to use the Estimator parameters
use_spot_instances:boolean | PipelineVariable,
max_wait: int | PipelineVariable | None,
max_run: int | PipelineVariable | None,

If use_spot_instances evaluates to True then max_wait and max_run must evaluate to int, otherwise they must to None (otherwise you end up with "ClientError: Failed to invoke sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob. Error Details: Invalid MaxWaitTimeInSeconds. It is only supported when EnableManagedSpotTraining is set to true")
The issue I have is How do you define max_wait and max_run as PipelineVariable such that they're either None or int depending on the (runtime) value of use_spot_instances?
I don't know if this is a UI issue - but if I declare
max_wait = ParameterInteger(
    name="MaxWait",
    default_value=14400,
)

The when I create an execution using Sagemaker Studio it requires that I provide a value for every parameter. It doesn't appear possible to pass "None", unless there's some way of declaring parameters as Optional that I'm missing?
Also if I try starting the execution from the cli I get
aws sagemaker start-pipeline-execution \
--pipeline-name model \
--pipeline-execution-display-name executions-20240923-03 \
--pipeline-parameters Name=UseSpotInstances,Value=false Name=MaxRun,Value=None Name=MaxRun,Value=None

I get
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the StartPipelineExecution operation: Encountered errors when validating the provided pipeline parameters. Parameter 'MaxRun' has type 'Integer' but was provided with an incompatible value of 'None'. Parameter 'MaxRun' has type 'Integer' but was provided with an incompatible value of 'None'. 

My main requirement is the ability to disable spot training when invoking from Sagemaker Studio - as recently I've not been able to get a spot instance at all. Is there a runtime way of doing
max_wait = max_wait if use_spot_instances else None

where the rhs values are Parameters and the condition is executed at runtime?
